# Display length of geo files with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geospatial, turfjs

I'm trying to build a webpage where I could put files (gpx, kml, geojson...), and Leaflet would display the routes on the map, each of them having a popup with their name and their length in km.
I managed to do it all, except for the length... My problem is that turf or cheap-ruler only accept geometries in order to calculate a length, and I can't manage to extract the geometry of my files to give it to turf.

Here is my code:

```
const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
  fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const fileList = event.target.files;
    console.log(fileList);
    for (file of fileList) {
        fileName = file.name
        extension = fileName.split('.').pop()
        var ObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)
        var line = turf.lineString(ObjectURL)
        var length = turf.length(line, {units: 'meters'})
        var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
            onEachFeature(feature, layer)
            {layer.bindPopup('<p><b>' + fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '</b></p><p>' + length + '</p>')}
        })
        if (extension == 'kml') {
            omnivore.kml(ObjectURL, null, customLayer).addTo(mymap)}
        else if (extension == 'gpx') {
            omnivore.gpx(ObjectURL, null, customLayer).addTo(mymap)}
        else if (extension == 'csv') {
            omnivore.csv(ObjectURL, null, customLayer).addTo(mymap)}
        else if (extension == 'wkt') {
            omnivore.wkt(ObjectURL, null, customLayer).addTo(mymap)}
        else if (extension == 'geojson') {
            omnivore.geojson(ObjectURL, null, customLayer).addTo(mymap)}
    }});
```

Here the problem is that ObjectURL is not a geojson object, so I tried another way, by putting the result of omnivore.gpx in a variable :

```
if (extension == 'gpx') {
        layer_gpx = omnivore.gpx(ObjectURL).addTo(mymap)}
        var line = turf.getCoord(layer_gpx)
        var length = turf.length(layer_gpx, {units: 'meters'})
        L.geoJson(layer_gpx, {
            onEachFeature(feature, layer)
            {layer.bindPopup('<p><b>' + fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + '</b></p><p>' + length + '</p>')
        }})
```

It still gives the error "No valid coordinates".
Thanks!

Edit : I found by myself!

```
var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
            onEachFeature(feature, layer)
            {layer.bindPopup('<p><b>' + feature.properties.name + '</b></p><p>'+ turf.length(feature.geometry, {units: 'kilometers'}) + ' km</p>')}
        })
```

Comment: Nice having found a solution by yourself! :-) Please consider posting it as an _answer_ below and _accepting_ it, so that people know your issue is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I don't know yet all the uses of SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found by myself, and here is the complete code I used:

```
const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
  fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const fileList = event.target.files;
    console.log(fileList);

    for (file of fileList) {
        fileName = file.name
        extension = fileName.split('.').pop()

        var ObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file)       

        var customLayer = L.geoJson(null, {
            onEachFeature(feature, layer)
            {layer.bindPopup('<p><b>' + feature.properties.name + '</b></p><p>'+ turf.length(feature.geometry, {units: 'kilometers'}) + ' km</p>')}
        })      

        if (extension == 'kml') {
            omnivore.kml(ObjectURL, null, customLayer).addTo(mymap)}

        else if (extension == 'gpx') {
            omnivore.gpx(ObjectURL, null, customLayer).addTo(mymap)}

        else if (extension == 'geojson') {
            omnivore.geojson(ObjectURL, null, customLayer).addTo(mymap)}

    }});
```

I abandoned csv and wkt formats because they don't comply to feature.geometry request, and I didn't really needed them.